# How to start an application in terminal?

Tags: terminal, desktop-environment

I run an application by opening a terminal then navigating to a directory and executing `./nameofapp`. The application opens in terminal and I can operate it with some other commands.

If I try to run the application from file manager, it runs in the background. How can I run it in terminal?

Comment: How do you open it outside of the command line? Is it a script or is it compiled?

Comment: @k.stm It is a executable file, to be concrete, in the "Properties" it says: application/x-executable.

Comment: That’s not what I meant. In the commandline, what does `$ file nameofapp` say? Maybe it’s not binary, but a text file. What does `$ head -n 3 nameofapp` say (the first three lines of the file)? More importantly, how do you open it outsite of the command line? Double-click on it in a file browser?

Comment: Yes I double click it, it is a compiled application that when launched only run in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [*.desktop*](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) file for your application. With `terminal` option the application should launch in terminal:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Application Name
Exec=/path/to/nameofapp
Terminal=true
```

Alternatively, you can write a wrapper script that starts terminal and runs your application. For example (gnome-terminal):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gnome-terminal -- ./nameofapp
```

Comment: I tried the second option and it opens and closes inmediately, when run through terminal with "./name-of-script" it says "exec: gnome-terminal not found". Sorry for my limited knowledge, I am beginner on Linux.

Comment: You need to call a terminal application installed on system (instead of `gnome-terminal`). What distribution/desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I am using the built-in terminal on Linux 19 Tara

Comment: Your system possibly uses `mate-terminal`. Try modifying the script by replacing `gnome-terminal` with `mate-terminal`.

Comment: it opens the terminal but don't do anything, I guess it is a problem in the app. However, thanks a lot for your answer!